# Failed to Deploy Flask to Azure

Tags: python, web-services, azure, flask

I'm trying to deploy `python` `flask` to `azure` but can not get it through. I create a api service on `Azure`

Here is the `url` for my `api`, and it serves with `python 3` https://textclassifier.azurewebsites.net/

then I created a default `flask` project on `visual studio`, without changing any code, I click publish directly. Chosen the the app service I created from portal, publishing shows successfully in `VS` Output:

> Adding file (TextClassifier\TestFlask__init__.py). Adding ACLs for path (TextClassifier) Adding ACLs for path (TextClassifier) Publish Succeeded. Web App was published successfully http://textclassifier.azurewebsites.net/ ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== ========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

However, when I access url `https://textclassifier.azurewebsites.net/home` browers shows : " The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable".

I checked that /home is routed to a controller

Can anyone help me out, I have been stuck for days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my experience, your issue is resulted from the azure app python environment. Please refer to my work steps and see if the error still shows up.

As you found in the [Managing Python on Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service) , Azure App Service provide you with a `site extension`. You could install packages on `KUDU console`.

Step 1 : Create azure web app and add Extensions(here is Python 3.6.1 x64)

[image]

Step 2 : Publish your `flask` project and add the `web.config`.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<Your Project Name>.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Step 3: Switch to the Kudu CMD and commands `cd Python361x64` and `touch get-pip.py` and copy the content of the url `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` into the `get-pip.py` via Edit button, then run `python get-pip.py` to install the pip tool.

[image]

Step 4 : Install any packages you need via `python -m pip install pyodbc`

[image]

Hope it helps you. Any concern ,please let me know.