# How to run python3.7 based flask web api on azure

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to host my python api on azure web app. It is a Flaks based application and having a demo flask code . I have created resource group and setup everything. But when accessing the url it shows

[image]

although I can see from the deployment options, it has successfully deployed my bitbucket project. I have selected python3.4 version in the application settings. I have tried adding the latest python extension but only 3.6version is available. I have added the python3.6 extension but it still only show python3.4 in application settings.

I do not know how can I resolve this issue. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try manually to make sure the deployment is successful into Azure, through `Kudo (Advance Tools/App Service Editor )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Flask Deployment - WSGI Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518358/azure-flask-deployment-wsgi-interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S Andrew.

`web.config` file is essential in the deployment of your web App.You could create the web.config file on the KUDU url.

You could navigate to KUDU via below two way:

1.Find the button on the portal.

[image]

2.access url directly: https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/

On the KUDU,you could see your app structure in the path: `D:\home\site\wwwroot`,you need to create `web.config` file here.

[image]

Also,you could see your python extension in the path:`D:\home\`, if you want to use extension environment, you need to configure the correct path in `web.config`.

[image]

Please see my sample `web.config` file.Related to `web.config`, you could refer to this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-python-configure#webconfig).

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<your app name>.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

More details about python app deployment on the azure,please see my previous cases,you will find the answer.

1.[Failed to Deploy Flask to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816080/failed-to-deploy-flask-to-azure/50832841#50832841)

2.[deploying python flask project on azure using visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507268/deploying-python-flask-project-on-azure-using-visual-studio/51510011#51510011)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definitely try this and will get back to you.

Comment: @SAndrew Sure,waiting for you reply.

Comment: @Yes. I created the `web.config` file but python was not in `D:\home`, it was in D:\ so I used this path in web.config. Also you mentioned that we need to write our app name in value  for `WSGI_HANDLER` in `web.config` but python file has extension `.py` not `.app`.? Its still not working.

Comment: @SAndrew Do you have time to join this chat :https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178670/pythonwebapp

Comment: Yes. I am in the chat now. Lets continue there.

Comment: Just want to let you know that it worked perfectly fine after creating the project using visual studio. Thanks for all your help and support.

Comment: @SAndrew Great !

Comment: Hi. Just wanted to know one thing, I have `input.json` which my main python file is using to get some input configurations. In the kudu console, I can see it inside `D:\home\site\wwwroot>` but when I check logs of `wfastcgi.log`, it says `No such file or directory: 'D:\\home\\python364x64\\devconfig.json'`. Why it is looking the file inside `D:\\home\\python354x64`. Where do I mention the correct path of the file. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026530/where-to-mention-path-of-files-in-azure-flask-based-python-app

Comment: @JayGong Still not working. getting error "  An error has occurred during web site deployment." Unsupported runtime python 3.6

Comment: @RagavanRajan Sorry for late,which case?

Comment: @JayGong added web.config in wwwroot folder. Getting the above error

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a webconfig file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="main.app"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python364x86\python.exe|D:\home\Python364x86\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Make sure to change the value of main.app to whatever your file name is and to change the path for python to your path. This solved the issue for me.

Comment: Hi, where did you get this weconfig file. Can you please share link. Or can you please add some explanation like why you have set `PYTHONAPTH` value to `D:\home\site\wwwroot"/`.

Comment: yes pls tell why did you set the PYTHON path to`D:\home\site\wwwroot` pls