# Where to mention path of files in azure flask based python app

Tags: python, azure

I have a `Flask` based python web app which is running fine on azure. I have made some changes and added a `input.json` file which contains some project configuration. I have below files in the project root directory:

```
app.py -> Main python file
input.json -> Input configuration file used by app.py
requirements.txt -> This file contains python packages used by project
web.config -> Azure web config file
```

Below is the content of `web.config` file

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="app.wsgi_app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python364x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python364x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is all working fine on my local machine. But when I deployed this on azure, API was not running. I opened the kudu console and checked the logs of `wfastcgi.log`, it was showing error:

`No such file or directory: 'D:\\home\\python364x64\\input.json'`

The problem is `input.json` is located inside `D:\home\site\wwwroot>` but it is automatically picking up the wrong path and thus failing the code.

**1. Why it is looking for `input.json` file in wrong path.?**

**2. How can I mention the correct path for `input.json` file.?**

**3. If in future, I'll add more files, where should I correctly mention path of all the files. Do we have to mention this in `web.config` file.?**

Thanks.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pretty sure you need to use relative path, something like this:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), 'input.json')
```

so you will get path in the same directory your python file is located. And this is not related to web.config. your python file attempts to load this file (this is my assumption). hence its looking for it in the path relative to the interpreter, not your python file.

Comment: Hi. I have now moved the input.json file into a configs folder in the project and using it like this `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'configs', 'devconfig.json')`. It works fine on my local machine but when deployed on azure, it shows the same error. I am confused on what I am doing wrong.