# Azure deployment redirect (Invalid login. Please try again.)

Tags: python, azure, iis, flask

I have deployed the base version of the Flask Appbuilder application on azure under the URL: [Site URL](https://sitetester.azurewebsites.net/login/). The admin login has been created using the Kudu console with ID as admin and password as admin The login keeps on redirecting to itself with an "Invalid login. Please try again." error, however the user exists in the app.db file itself. The redirect does not create any logs on Azure.

[image: Error portion and log]

We have an important deployment coming up, any leads to resolve this would be appreciated.

Thanks

#### Environment

Flask-Appbuilder version: latest

Comment: Python apps should be hosted on Azure App Service on Linux now, https://blog.lextudio.com/shifting-to-azure-app-service-on-linux-b216f4584b03

Comment: I will try to migrate to linux, in the meantime would anyone have any lead to get it working.

Comment: Would anyone have any idea on how to go about resolving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your Python application built by `flask-appbuilder` was deployed on Azure WebApp for Windows, but not works.

There are my answers for two existing SO threads [Hosting Flask(Python) app throws CGI error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121080/hosting-flaskpython-app-throws-cgi-error/54142861#54142861) and [Hosting Flask(python) API on Azure API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906301/hosting-flaskpython-api-on-azure-api/53910872#53910872).

I tried to create a demo via `flask-appbuilder` in Python 3 and deploy it to Azure WebApp for Windows, then it works fine. Here is my steps below which you can refer to.

1. I create a virtual environment for this demo via the commands below on my local machine that I have installed Python 3 runtime and `virtualenv` via `pip install virtualenv`.

   ```
   virtualenv demo
   cd demo
   bin\activate.bat
   pip install flask-appbuilder
   fabmanager create-app # use `demoapp` as the `Your new app name` input
   cd demoapp
   ```
2. To create admin with all default options and a simple password via `fabmanager create-admin`.

   ```
   Username [admin]:
   User first name [admin]:
   User last name [user]:
   Email [admin@fab.org]:
   Password:
   Repeat for confirmation:
   D:\<your path>\demo\demoapp\lib\python3.6\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:794: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
     'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
   2019-02-21 15:29:55,309:INFO:flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.manager:Security DB not found Creating all Models from Base
   2019-02-21 15:29:55,334:INFO:flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.manager:Security DB Created
   .......
   ```
3. I run the `demoapp` via `fabmanager run` and it works on my local.
4. Then, I drag all my directories and files of `demoapp` that include `app.db` into my Azure WebApp via Kudo Console `https://<your webapp name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.
5. Due to not directly install the app dependencies for `flash-appbuilder`, I installed a Python 3 runtime in the `Site extensions` of Kudu, as the figure below.

   [image]
6. Continues, I back to Kudu Console and run the commands below to install `flask-appbuilder`.

   D:\home>cd python364x64
   D:\home\python364x64>python -V
   Python 3.6.4
   D:\home\python364x64>pip install flask-appbuilder
   Collecting flask-appbuilder
     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/b0/edb3e54241203266222c4863ae6eb30fd49f5d331a117b61f1801e8124da/Flask-AppBuilder-1.12.3.tar.gz (2.3MB)
   Requirement already satisfied: colorama<1,>=0.3.9 in d:\home\python364x86\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder) (0.4.1)
   Requirement already satisfied: click<8,>=6.7 in d:\home\python364x86\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder) (7.0)
   ......
7. Then, to move into `site\wwwroot` to create & configure a `web.config` file and change the code in `run.py`. There are two ways to make it works, as below.

   - Not using WSGI. The default port of Azure WebApp is depended on the environment variable `HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT` which be set by IIS on Azure. So we need to change the `port` parameter of `app.run` method in `run.py` and configure `web.config` as below.

   The `run.py` code changed as below:

   ```
   from app import app
   import os

   app.run(port=int(os.environ['HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT']))
   ```

   And the `web.config` content as below:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
       <appSettings>
           <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
           <add key="PATH" value="D:\home\python364x64;D:\home\python364x64\Scripts;%PATH%" />
       </appSettings>
       <system.webServer>
           <handlers>
               <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
           </handlers>
           <httpPlatform processPath="D:\home\python364x64\python.exe" arguments="D:\home\site\wwwroot\run.py --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" startupRetryCount='10'>
           </httpPlatform>
         </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```

   - Using WSGI server instead for production environment.

   The `run.py` code as below.

   ```
   from app import app

   app.run()
   ```

   And the `web.config` content as below.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
        <appSettings>
             <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
             <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="app.app" />
        </appSettings>
        <system.webServer>
             <handlers>
                 <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python364x64\python.exe|D:\home\python364x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
             </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```

It works via access `https://<your app name>.azurewebsites.net`
[image]